# About Intelligent Power Modules for H-Bridge Configuration

Tags: motor, power-electronics, gate-driving, igbt

For some days I have been searching for some kind of compact, easy to use and well powered modules that can be drive BDC motor using H-bridge configuration which gate trigger signal from MCU will be Hin-Lin PWM for each half bridges. Since the nominal voltage of the power line will be approximately 100 Vdc 9 A, as soon as I know, published generic BDC motor driver chips can only support maximum of 72 Vdc with low power so cannot be usefull for me. Because of that, I have been looking for some kind of powerful compact device like intelligent power modules (IPM). Since many times, I had been used lots of IPMs at my designs and from today they are perfect for cost & space & BOM saving but IPMs are generally for 3 phase applications like BLDC motors. Today I have thought that what will happens if I use only 4 IGBT (H-bridge) of inside IPM and pull down other two IGBT's gate sources for like completely closed switch. So that way, I can use six-pack IGBT as a H-bridge. Since I don’t want to complicate the design and higher the PCB cost, I don’t want to use half bridge gate drivers with discrete IGBTs. There are really cheap (compared to use discreate components) IPM modules available on global markets so that would be great if I could use IPM for my application.

What do you think about it? Can I use six pack IPM module as a H-bridge?

Thank you.

Comment: The question is a bit broad. There is more to say if you provide an example of such an 3 phase IPM.

Comment: @Jens For example Infineon IGCM20F60GA IPM. This IPM is just for example not that choosen for my motor specifications. It integrated with gate driver , boostrap circuitry and some protection futures all in one package. This is extremly usefull when cost and BOM save is in first goal.

Comment: Today i saw a webpage that uses brushless driver as a brushed dc motor driver. Link is at below.
Link: https://www.electronics-lab.com/project/dc-motor-direction-controller-brake-using-mc33035/
what do you think about it ?

Comment: I don't see a problem in such a use case. In the unused half leg I would activate the low side FET to avoid undervoltage alarm of the high side driver supply. There will be a thermal gradient in the chip, but this would also be the case in a motor stall situation using 3 phases.